# How would I programmatically query multiple registered SQL Server instances?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm not sure what the solution is, so I'm putting this out there to get some feelers as to how this is achievable without just running the query against each database individually. If that's the solution, so be it, but I'd like to see if there is a means to running a single query against multiple registered SQL Server instances.

I have about 10 DBs that I've registered into a local server group, and I can query them all with the same query in SMSS. Now I'm trying to architect out a pattern in which I can query all of these DBs programmatically in some way, then take the results and dump them into a S3 bucket in our AWS environment. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your existing query?

Comment: It's simply a small query against a single table that exists in all 10 instances.

Comment: Maybe like [this via SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Your best bet for this is to create a linked server object..

Comment: There are many ways to do this; what is "best" depends on the specifics of your use case and the data set. For example, if this is an *ad hoc* sort of use case, and the data set is small, the best way is probably to open up Query Analyzer for each instance and cut and paste the resultset into Excel. If you need to do this on a recurring basis and the data set is huge, you may want to set up jobs that extract the data to flat files and another job to injest them. Etc. I can think of about a half dozen other ways.

Comment: @JohnWu The latter is what I want to do, but instead of running the query on each DB and getting flat files and ingesting... I'd rather run a single query against the registered servers. Can that be done programmatically?